# What is minimum value of $l$ where $l$ is one of the prependiculer line of triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, number-theory

$l,k,2$ are length of prependicular line of triangle$ABC$.Where $\frac{k+2}{k-2}$ is not integer ,but rational number, Integer $l$'s maximum  value is $f(k)$, find $f(k)$

I didn't have an idea to solve this problem. Please give some hint...

Comment: I would always start something like this by drawing and labelling a diagram.

Comment: @Bruce I'm sorry about I can't draw some diagram in tax..... I can't imagine condition $\frac{k+2}{k-2}$

Comment: Try first to define what **exactly** you mean by "perpendicular line of triangle"...Do you mean heights of the triangle? Perpendicular bisectors of the sides and their length to their common point? I really can't understand that.

Comment: @DonAntonio yes,It's three hight of triangle

Comment: @user366725 Good...then I only don't understand the rest: The three heights of a triangle have lengths $\;l,\,k,\,2\;$ , right? You're given $\;\frac{k+2}{k-2}\;$ is a rational number. Then you say, I think, that the maximum value $\;l\;$ can attain is $\;f(k)\;$ , which I suppose means a number depending only on $\;k\;$ ...Yep, I've no idea what to do. Perhaps some diagram would help.There are sites that help you with this, and then you can glue the diagram here.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think one of hight is 2 and it is constant so it depends only k and k>2 .....

Comment: @DonAntonio I'd like you to give me some information about that site......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we set the Area of the triangle be “lkt”. Then the three sides of the triangle are 2kt, 2lt, and lkt. So, we have 2k+2l>lk, 2k+lk>2l, and 2l+lk>2k. To these, we have 2k>l(k-2), 2k>l(2-k), and (2+k)l>2k. if k is more than 2, l is less than 2k/(k-2). If k is less than 2, l is less than 2k/(2-k). if k is 2, l just needs to be more than 1.

Comment: if there are mistakes, I will revise the answer. and I do not know why (k+2)/(k-2) is post.

Comment: I'm sorry about that I didn't write correctly. \frac{k+2}{k-2} is rational number that is not integer. For example when k=3,5/1=5 So k=/=3

Comment: I'm sorry but would you explain more specifically?? I can't understand....TT

Comment: I mean the item about the rational number does not have any meaning in my opinion. It may just show that k is a rational number since (k+2)/(k-2)=1+4/(k-2)

Comment: Thank you to explain about that,but I didn't understand your answer........ what means Area is lkt?

Comment: just like 5x or 3x.

Comment: since I, k, and t are not constant. the multiply of them can show all the sequence that the area can be.

Comment: I mean it is like A=0.5*h*l. Both h and I can be changed.

Comment: oh okey I got it!!! Thanks a lot TT